# Arduino Multitasking possibilities

Tags: multiprocessing, microcontroller, android-wifi, arduino-uno

I am trying to do do project with Arduino uno, sensor, LED and WiFi shield. I am taking analog input of sensor data in Arduino uno. The basic program lit up an LED if the sensor value exceeds a threshold level. And this program is working fine. Now I want simultaneously to upload the input data to Google spreadsheet with the help of WiFi shield. After mounting the WiFi shield the basic functionality is even not getting executed. Hence I am wondering whether accessing two hardware level components simultaneously is supported by Arduino micro-controller or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arduino UNO microcontroller (ATmega328) is fully capable of multitasking, but this would require departure from how the Arduino "sketches" are traditionally structured. There are many possible approaches, such as event-driven programming or even a traditional preemptive real-time kernel (RTOS). I would recommend to take a look at event-driven programming. For example, on the Arduino Playground you can find a project "QP state machine framework for Arduino" (see http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/QP ). Among others, this project references an Application Note: "Event-Driven Arduino Programming" at http://www.state-machine.com/arduino/AN_Event-Driven_Arduino-1.5.x.pdf

Answer (score 2):

https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/288

> Protothreads are extremely lightweight stackless threads designed for
>   severely memory constrained systems, such as small embedded systems or
>   wireless sensor network nodes. Protothreads provide linear code
>   execution for event-driven systems implemented in C. Protothreads can
>   be used with or without an underlying operating system to provide
>   blocking event-handlers. Protothreads provide sequential flow of
>   control without complex state machines or full multi-threading.

example from the website of protothreads :

```
#include "pt.h"

struct pt pt;
struct timer timer;

PT_THREAD(example(struct pt *pt))
{
  PT_BEGIN(pt);

  while(1) {
    if(initiate_io()) {
      timer_start(&timer);
      PT_WAIT_UNTIL(pt,
         io_completed() ||
         timer_expired(&timer));
      read_data();
    }
  }
  PT_END(pt);
}
```

But dont **ever** use `while(1)` in any productive code, that will lock your arduino at some point - instead create a sensible sanity check and put it into the loopheader, maybe even put an IO-check there so you can stop the program via one of the hardware buttons -- which is not only a cool feature but also what some people call "good coding"